# How to troubleshoot slow computer?

Tags: windows, performance

Quite often I experience cases where I have the exact same computers with the same configuration. And one of them is slow, the other one is normal.

That is what I do to troubleshoot.

Create an environment to isolate software issues.

1. I reinstall Windows from scratch with the same ISO. - Excluding issues with OS and fragmentation.
2. Install only Microsoft office - Exclude issues with programs eating resources.
3. Install Windows and office updates up to date. - Exclude issues with Windows and office updates.

Troubleshoot hardware:

1. Bench cpu with cpu-z and cpubench - results are the same on both
   computers. However Cpubench itself opens much slower on the problem
   computer, so I suspect Disk drive. However...
2. Bench disk drive with CrystalDiskMark - give the same results. All 4
   rows are the same despite tiny bias. When I open something, in task
   manager I see disk 100%. But it still tells nothing, cause on fast
   computer I could catch disk load but it would disappear much faster.
3. Check RAM with memtest86 - No errors.

We purchase dell optiplex computers and dell support runs dell diagnostics and say that the computer is OK. Despite what they're saying, I could feel the difference. For example, excel opens on normal computer in 2 seconds, on problem computer - 4 seconds. And inside excel I could feel the difference.

What to troubleshoot next?

Comment: Sounds like a disk with slow seek times rather than actual speed. Are they set up the same in the firmware/BIOS?

Comment: Exact same hardware and configuration? Same software? What is the workload?

Comment: Yes, same hardware and software. The question is asked to find what exact steps required for troubleshooting slow performance. I guess everyone experienced struggle to find out the cause of slow.